# Convert DLL import from VB.NET to VB6

Tags: vb.net, api, winapi, vb6

I know it's unusual, but I have to port some code from VB.NET to VB6, and I need to convert 2 APIs to VB6.

To be honest, I have never written an API declaration in VB6, I have only copied it from websites and other code.

Could somebody tell me how I could convert the following code from VB.NET to VB6?

```
<DllImport("XInput1_4", EntryPoint:="XInputGetState", setlasterror:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function XInputGetState_1_4(ByVal dwUserIndex As UInteger, ByRef pState As XINPUT_STATE) As UInteger
    End Function


<DllImport("XInput9_1_0", EntryPoint:="XInputGetState", setlasterror:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function XInputGetState_9_1_0(ByVal dwUserIndex As UInteger, ByRef pState As XINPUT_STATE) As UInteger
    End Function
```

Is the following VB6 code correct?

```
Private Declare Function XInputGetState_1_4 Lib "XInput1_4.dll" (ByVal dwUserIndex As Long, ByRef pState As XINPUT_STATE) As Long

Private Declare Function XInputGetState_9_1_0 Lib "XInput9_1_0.dll" (ByVal dwUserIndex As Long, ByRef pState As XINPUT_STATE) As Long
```

Comment: Have you tried using this code?  In general I think it looks good.  If it doesn't work, you might try adding aliases.  For example `Alias "XInputGetState"`.

Comment: Probably, You can write functions in VB.NET the same way as VB6 just change longs to integers.

Comment: It's unclear, why your initial VB.NET code uses `SetLastError:=True`. COM doesn't use it to return error/success information.

Comment: It's not obviously wrong; the syntax is correct and the types are correct.  You might run into trouble with `XINPUT_STATE` depending on how it's defined.

Comment: I think you should add the aliases like Brian advised. And following up Craig's comment, you should post the definition of `XINPUT_STATE` in original VB.Net and also your VB6 version. That is also important.